# Please help me write scripts with AutoHotkey

Tags: autohotkey, game-physics

I've recently been inspired to the art of writing scripts on AutoHotkey.
I am a beginner who desperately needs your insight.
I would greatly appreciate your time and input on this matter.

*Primary Objective: Looping Script Interaction*

I'd like to have a single script running at a time which would trigger one another upon given events.
We have two scripts, let's name them A and B.
A's mission is to perform given tasks until it finds a specific image which would then trigger B.
B's mission is to perform given tasks with that image until it disappears which would then trigger back to A.

As far as the Looping Script Interaction, here's what I've got.

**Here's A.ahk:-**

```
Loop

  ImageSearch, PX, PY, 1, 1, 10, 10, %A_WorkingDir%image.png
  if ErrorLevel = 1
    WheelDown
  Else
    Run, %A_WorkingDir%B.ahk

Return
```

**Here's B.ahk:-**

```
Loop

  ImageSearch, PX, PY, 1, 1, 10, 10, %A_WorkingDir%image.png
  if ErrorLevel = 0
    Click %PX%, %PY%
  Else
    Run, %A_WorkingDir%A.ahk

Return
```

Please let me know if I am doing this correctly..
Also for the ImageSearch, can I write X, Y, instead of PX, PY?
I am wondering on their differences.

*Secondary Objective: Programming Mouse Movement*

I'm lacking knowledge giving some specific tasks to script A.
Here's the scenario, the game is called Legend of Darkness otherwise known as DarkAges.
It is a 2D game and my avatar is idle always shown in the center of the screen.
Once you push the spacebar, you trigger a teleport map overlapping the previous screen.
However, the teleport distance is limited which is shown on the teleport map in two colors.
Blue: Available for teleport
Red: Not available for teleport
Once you click a desired Blue zone, it is highlighted to Green.
Click the Green for confirmation, the avatar teleports.

Assuming the world being rectangular, I'd like my avatar to roam around the edge until it finds an image to trigger the B script. After dealing with the image, I'd like my avatar to continue the journey from the point B was triggered.

I just don't know how I should even start with this 'A' script.
I do understand that this is a broad question with many possible directions but any of your insights on which commands I should consider studying would at least start me off solving this problem.
Perhaps I should correspond the teleport limit by limiting the coordinates? Like X=n, Y=n

Once again, I appreciate your time reading this!
Any input will do wonders!

Comment: There is no need to have 2 scripts for this functionality.  Look up `SetTimer`, this seems like what you are looking for.

Comment: `Loop` will only loop the next command. You need to use brackets `{}` to enclose a block you want to loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A code that combined both loops would look like this.
One other loop, that starts first loop A, leaves loop A with the break command, then B, then leaves B, then loops itself.

```
Loop,

{

  ;loop A

  Loop,
  {
    ImageSearch, PX, PY, 1, 1, 10, 10, %A_WorkingDir%image.png
    if ErrorLevel = 1
      WheelDown
    Else
      break
  }

  ;loop B

  Loop,
  {
    ImageSearch, PX, PY, 1, 1, 10, 10, %A_WorkingDir%image.png
    if ErrorLevel = 0
      Click %PX%, %PY% 
    Else
      break
  }   

  Sleep, 100
}
```

Regarding PX,PY. These are variable names you can use any allowed variable name here. X and Y are totally fine.